# Как связать удалённую базу данных с телеграм-ботом на питоне?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Необходимо подключить бота на питоне к бд mysql и изменять её. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать это. Используется Sqlalchemy. Я в этом деле новичок и ориентируюсь плохо.

Comment: База MySQL? Указать ее адрес и настройки подключения (например логин и пароль)

Comment: A каким образом и куда это прописывать в коде питона? Да, mysql

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#mysql

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Я к mysql не подключался, поэтому только так и мог помочь. Если разобрались с проблемой, пожалуйста, оформите это как ответ :) Давать ответы на свои вопросы хорошая практика